# Set the colour of the application in PyQt4

Tags: python, colors, pyqt4

Normally, all the applications in PyQt4, has grey colour as default. The tool bar, the menu bar, status bar, title bar are by default grey. Can it be possible to change it to some other colour instead of grey. I know it is dependent on the OS on which it is being run, but does PyQt allows to do so??

Comment: Are you using designer?

Comment: haha .. No I was just curious .. :)

Comment: Well yes you can easily change it :-)

Answer (score 1):

PyQt allows to use [CSS](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples/).

### Example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore as core
from PyQt4 import QtGui as gui
import sys


if '__main__' == __name__:

    app = gui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    CSS = """
        QMainWindow{
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    """

    window_1 = gui.QMainWindow(None)
    window_1.setFixedSize(300, 300)
    window_1.show()

    window_2 = gui.QMainWindow(None)
    window_2.setFixedSize(300, 300)
    window_2.show()

    # Uncomment next line to make all windows yellow
    # app.setStyleSheet(CSS) 

    # Uncomment next line to make all just window_1 yellow
    # window_1.setStyleSheet(CSS)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that title bar color depends on the theme running.